# How to transliterate, when citing an author which has already been transliterated to another language?

Tags: translation, style

While writing in German, suppose you need to quote somebody, whose German transliteration differs from the transliteration as appears in the language of the work you want to do the citation from, for instance, *Chaikovski* and *Tschaikowski.*

> *blah blah*, so Tschaikowski (cf. [Tjaj85]).
>   *Mehr text auf Deutsch.*

and in the references

> Literatur
>   [Tjaj85] Pjotr I. Tjajkovskij, "Title of some work in Danish", Jour. of App. Symph. Mus. 1885

Can I homogenize the transliteration in favor of German, or am I expected to respect the original and thus having two inconsistent names of an author along my text?

Comment: Note that neither _Tschaikowski_ nor _Tjajkovskij_ are [transliterations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_transcription); instead, they are [transcriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration). A transliteration is a 1:1 mapping between letters; e.g., a transliteration would never represent _Ч_ (one Cyrillic letter) as _Tsch_ or _Tj_ (four or two Latin letters).

Comment: Regarding the question, I think I’d give my preferred version in square brackets, like this: _Pjotr I. Tjajkovskij [= Pjotr Iljitsch Tschaikowski], „Den danske Titeln“, …_

Comment: Last note: Since it‘s not really specific to German, might the question be better suited for Academia.SE?

Comment: This isn't really german-specific. Move to academia.stackexchange?

Comment: Doch doch: rules for writing words from foreign languages and scripts are highly-language dependent.  (I mean, nobody is suggesting using the actual Cyrillic in German ever, whereas in Russian it's perfectly fine to write 'YouTube' or 'Bosch' in many contexts.)

Comment: I haven’t dealt with this in an academic context yet myself and I would assume it depends more on the house style than language, but if I had to I would do something like @chirlu suggested, but maybe using _als_ ‘as’ like IMDb, for instance, does. In Biblatex, there would be the `nameaddon` field for uses like that, by the way.

Comment: The reference of a citation is suppose to make looking up the citation in context easy, in case the reader wants to do so. So I'd use whatever spelling is used in the publication itself. Changing the transcription could make it harder to google it, or it could mess with alphabetical sorting in a library. In the text itself, I'd prefer to use a well-known transcription ("Tschaikowski", as you have done) to make it easier for the reader to recognize the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write the citation in the way of the original and leave it to the intelligence of the audience to recognize, that the name refers to the same person, mentioned in another style before.

The whole idea of citation is, to be pedantically exact.